# Enlarge image on mouse hover inside a table

Tags: jquery, css

Actually i saw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uCtHh/367/) tutorial for giving zoom in effect on mouse over to an image
here images are not in any table so can i achieve same effect by putting images inside a 
table and set the positions of images to relative?

like

```
    <table border = '2'>
     <tr>
      <td>
         <img id="a1" src="http://demos.frnzzz.com/imgZoom/1.jpg" height="50"  width="50">
      </td>
      <td>
         <img id="a2" src="http://demos.frnzzz.com/imgZoom/1.jpg" height="50" width="50">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

when i tried to put images inside a table effect is changing, it also increasing size
of table but size of table should remain as it is.

i am using following code for giving zoom in and zoom out effects to images but it works good in mozilla firefox but not working in google chrome. in chrome it is also extending table column size, (z-index not working), img1 is inside a table tag.

```
  function zoomIn(indexNo){
    var zoomin = $('#img1').attr("zoomin");
    if(zoomin == "false")
        {
            $('#img1').css("z-index", 1);
            $('#img1').css("position", "absolute");
            $('#img1').animate({
               height  :    l_imgHeightZoomIn,
               width   :    l_imgWidthZoomIn,
               left    :    l_imgLeftZoomIn,
               top     :    l_imgTopZoomIn
            }, "slow");
            $('#img1').attr("zoomin", "true");
        }
    }
--------------------------------------------------------------
  function zoomOut(indexNo){
    var zoomin = $('#img1').attr("zoomin");
    if(zoomin == "true")
        {
            $('#img1').css("z-index", 0);
            $('#img1').css("position", "static");
            $('#img1').animate({
                height : l_imgHeight,
                width  : l_imgWidth,
                left   : l_imgLeftZoomOut,
                top    : l_imgTopZoomOut
            }, 0);
            $('#img11').attr("zoomin", "false");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I read your question I think you are looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8umD4/4/.

```
 img:hover
 {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:90%;
   height:90%;
 }
.formatTable td
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
}  
<table border = '2' class='formatTable'>
 <tr><td>
    <img id="a1" src="http://demos.frnzzz.com/imgZoom/1.jpg" height="50" width="50" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <img id="a2" src="http://demos.frnzzz.com/imgZoom/1.jpg" height="50" width="50"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Check it out. If it doesn't meet your requirement, please explain more about your problem.

Comment: actually http://jsfiddle.net/uCtHh/381/ is looking a good effect. in your case table's columns size is already very large can it be same as image and on mouse hover only image gets zoom in effect.

Comment: OK you want to maintain the effect, now watch my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8umD4/10/ I have updated it.

Comment: thanks for your efforts but if i change it like this jsfiddle.net/8umD4/15/ now can you maintain same effect?

Comment: To enlarge the image inside the table you have to set the size of the table cell greater than the image otherwise at the time of enlarging image the size of table will change according to the size of image. Now check this http://jsfiddle.net/8umD4/16/.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/8umD4/16  this is same you just has removed the border of the table but i need border of table, and table column size should be same as image size on mouse over image should get zoom in but not table columns, table columns should remain of same size. i don't even that is possible or not. thanks for your reply

Comment: so you mean it is not possible what i want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23550/discussion-between-user460293-and-mitali)